# WordPress Light/Dark Theme best practices? Is there a way that really works?

Tags: css, cookies

We currently have a light/dark theme enabled on our WordPress site using cookies and a .dark class in CSS. It works, but makes using WP Total Cache almost not worth it as any post/page using the cookie cannot be page cached. I tried using localstorage instead, but was unable to get past an annoying "flash" when changing pages: each new navigation loads the default light css, then applies the dark css, resulting in a glimpse of the light theme before switching, very annoying. I was able to minimize the flash, but it's still there.
I'm not finding any plugins that solve the light/dark theme question, and so far remain stuck using cookies and accepting that caching just isn't possible 
Does anyone have a working example of light/dark theme switching that works with caching, and actually works?

Comment: Hi {user}, welcome to [wordpress.se]. As a rule, the community considers questions about third-party plugins (such as WP Total Cache) off-topic so you might notice some down-votes and answers may be slow if they come at all. Additionally, the community is not too fond of plugin requests. You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It may be worth bringing this up with the theme creator.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you're testing for user preferences?  There are some good suggestions in this related post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840168/how-to-detect-if-the-os-is-in-dark-mode-in-browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can try fragment caching (https://www.justinsilver.com/technology/wordpress/w3-total-cache-fragment-caching-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks. The problem with fragment caching (as I understand it, and I'm far more of a webmaster than a developer), is that as *every* post/page is either light or dark, you would have to make every page dynamic, which is in effect what I'm already doing by having page caching turned off altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your own theme (that you made) I have some suggestions. If the theme is third-party, I suggest making a child theme (lots of helpful advice on Google about this).

As you are using a cookie to pick light or dark, you should be able to hook the enqueued styles and dequeue the unwanted one with the [style_loader_tag filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/style_loader_tag/).

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag',  'fix_style_choice', 10, 4 );
function fix_style_choice( $html, $handle, $href, $media ){
    // check cookies and only enqueue the right style (dequeue the wrong one).
}
```

My guess is this could sort out the problem.

As Tom Broucke points out, fragment caching could also help.

Another approach may be to give the two style sheets a very short (or a very long) cache time.

Finally, there is also a [Javascript solution to the flash of unstyled content issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3221561/1499072).